# Move multiple SQL Server 2008 databases from C: to D: at once

Tags: database, disk-space, sql-server-2008

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 with 323 databases consuming some 14 GB on my C: drive, a fast SSD.

Because I want to reclaim some space on my C: drive, I would like to move them to my D: drive.

I have found [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345483%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), but that seems to be the procedure to move only one database.

Is there an automatic way or script to move all my databases at once?

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat and link the directory across drives after you move it. Then no changes need to be done within the database configuration.

```
mklink /d MovedDirectory D:\MovedToDirectory
```

Comment: Will this also give the same NTFS rights to `D:\MovedToDirectory` as there were originally on `C:\MovedDirectory`?